# Carousel js. Slider doesn't work.How to make it work correctly?

Tags: javascript

I think I made a mistake in js code because it doesn't work when I click . There are no actions . What should I change in  js code?Thanks. My js code:

```js
const slides = document.querySelector(".slides");
const slidesCount = slides.childElementCount;
console.log(slidesCount)
const nextBtn=document.querySelector(".next-slide");
const prevBtn=document.querySelector(".prev-slide");
const container = document.querySelector('.slider-container')

//Controls
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeSlide('prev')
})
  
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeSlide('next')
})
let activeSlideIndex = 0

function changeSlide(direction) {
  if(direction === 'prev') {
    activeSlideIndex++
    if(activeSlideIndex === slidesCount) {
      activeSlideIndex = 0
    }
  } else if(direction === 'next') {
    activeSlideIndex--
    if(activeSlideIndex < 0) {
      activeSlideIndex = slidesCount - 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here my html code.

```
            <button class="prev-slide">&#9665;</button>
            <button class="next-slide">&#9655;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="slides">
         <img class="slide"  src="images/picture1.jpg" alt="slide image">
          <img class="slide" src="images/picture2.jpg" alt="slide image">
          <img class="slide" src="images/picture3.jpg" alt="slide image">
        </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a few other things for us to be able to help you. Can you post your html? Also, which carousel library are you using?

Comment: I have added the html code

Comment: That looks better, and now just which carousel lib is it?  Maybe you can try recreating the example, say on stackblitz? Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vnxwjr?file=index.html)?

Comment: It want to do it without any lib

Comment: Ahaa, okay, then we're still missing some code. E.g. where is your `changeSlide` function defined, we don't see it.

Comment: hope now you can see it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing missing was the actual rendering. You have to somehow hide or show the active slide. I've done that by adding `active` class and only showing that (through CSS). Then your changeSlide function does not only calculate the active slide, but also set the class on the appropriate element.

```js
const slides = document.querySelector(".slides");
const slidesCount = slides.childElementCount;
console.log(`Showing ${slidesCount} slides.`)
const nextBtn=document.querySelector(".next-slide");
const prevBtn=document.querySelector(".prev-slide");
const container = document.querySelector('.slider-container')

//Controls
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeSlide('prev')
})
  
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeSlide('next')
})
let activeSlideIndex = 0

function changeSlide(direction) {
  if(direction === 'prev') {
    activeSlideIndex++
    if(activeSlideIndex === slidesCount) {
      activeSlideIndex = 0
    }
  } else if(direction === 'next') {
    activeSlideIndex--
    if(activeSlideIndex < 0) {
      activeSlideIndex = slidesCount - 1
    }
  }
  Array.from(slides.children).forEach((slide, idx) => {
    if (idx === activeSlideIndex) {
      slide.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      slide.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }); 
}
```

```css
.controls {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.slides .slide {
  display: none
}

.slides .slide.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section  class="controls">
  <button class="prev-slide">&#9665;</button>
  <button class="next-slide">&#9655;</button>
</section>
      
<div class="slides">
  <img class="slide active"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x250" alt="slide image">
  <img class="slide" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/250" alt="slide image">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/250" alt="slide image">
</div>
```

Comment: It works. One more question when I add to this code  transform style it doesn't work.                 My code:"const weigth= container.clientWeigth;
   //slides.style.transition = 'transform 1.5s ease';
   slides.style.transform =`translateX(${activeSlideIndex * weigth}px)`". I will appreciate your help ))))

Comment: That's a CSS question, you can probably find an example here on Stackoverflow. If not, just ask another question, that's what the site is for :)